# How to use MS office 2007 and MS Office 2010 simultaneously on a single Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

Recently I installed MS Office 2010 as a separate installation(not upgrade) on my Windows Vista. I want to use both MS office 2007 and MS Office 2010.
But whenever I switch to Word 2007 from Word 2010 or vice-versa, a Configuration process starts which is like a setup of Word and it take lot of time.
Is there any way of using both Offices simultaneously?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: The main reason I want this is that my family members are obsessed with Office 2007 and I am really comfortable with Office 2010.

Comment: Try installing it to your respective Application Data (C:\Users\USERNAME\Application Data\) folders (assuming that you have different accounts).

Comment: No. Only one user account!

Comment: I have 2003, 2007, and 2010 on a machine.  I gotta make sure new programs play nice since some users still refuse to move out of the stone age. . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2121447) is a page that microsoft has on the topic. It seems that so long as you are using the 32 bit version of office 2010, and installed the versions in the correct order (earliest to latest), everything will work out.

Perhaps the most important thing to note is that Outlook 2010 **cannot** co-exist with the previous version of office.

Here are the steps to prevent the auto-reregistration of word 2010:

> 1. Exit Word 2010.
>      Start Registry Editor.
> 2. In Windows 7 or Windows Vista, click Start, type regedit in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
>
>    - If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
>    - In Windows XP, click Start , click Run , type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK .
> 3. Locate and then click to select the following registry subkey: 
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\Options
> 4. After you select the subkey that is specified in step 3, point to New on the Edit menu, and then click DWORD Value.
> 5. Type NoReReg , and then press ENTER.
> 6. Right-click NoReReg , and then click Modify.
> 7. In the Valuedata box, type 1, and then click OK.
> 8. On the File menu, click Exit to close Registry Editor.

Comment: hey @soandos what is the step 3 in step 7?

Comment: Sorry, bad numbering. I am fixing now. @AshutoshDave, done.

Comment: yes, Outlook cannot co-exist! and yes..it works!! thanx a lot @soandos!!

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If other less resource-intensive methods fail, and you have a valid Windows licence, you can use some virtual machine software (like [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.com)) to run another Windows installation with totally separate settings and programs from inside a window on you main Windows Vista, as if it was just another program. If you go for Virtualbox, check its *seamless* mode for a better experience.